# How does the --bsize option in fio work?

Tags: filesystems, io, fio

Since fio is a benchmarking tool that for each run, should simulate a real I/O workload, how does the --bsize option fit with that? My understanding is that the filesystem has a set block size for which an application issuing a read/write operation has to use? The app wants to read let's say 256KiB of data. If the filesystem uses a block size of 4KiB then that would be broken down into 64 blocks. If I were to use fio to simulate this, but set the bsize to 256KiB, would that have any effect on the read operation? The filesystem wouldn't write 1 block but still 64 blocks, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. The idea of blocksize is to create near realistic example of load. You can't find very much files with size 512 bytes or 4k bytes. So you can play with different blocksize (even with size of 128MB) to "emulate" different type of load.